# Express: pass variable for all templates

Tags: node.js, express

I try to pass variable to all templates. In app.js I wrote:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
       res.locals.token = '1234';
       next();
   });
```

But if I try to get my variable in template, such as

```
span= token
```

I get an error = 'token is not defined'.
What is wrong?

I use Express 3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably to do with *where* in app.js you put that function. It has to be before the routing middleware, otherwise it won't get called.

Assuming your app.js file has a line like:

```
app.use(app.router)
```

Then your function needs to be put before that.